# If there is no racism in Islam, why are Syeds not allowed to take Zakaat/Charity?

Tags: zakat, sadaqah, ahl-ul-bayt, ummah

Islam doesn't believe in racism or superiority of one caste over the other one. But according to majority of the scholars, Syeds (descendants of Prophet S.A.W's family) do not take zakaat because of the following reason :

**According to the meaning of one Hadith, Zakat is like the filth taken off the wealth, hence that's why it can't not be given to descendants of Holy Prophet S.A.W's family**

**"Charity (Zakah) is not becoming for the family of Muhammad, as it is people's impurities. "**
[Sahih Muslim, Book on Zakah, no.1072]

JazakAllah

Comment: Do you have more questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no racism in Islam. I will try to explain as much as I can. According to the fatwa of *The General Presidency of Scientific Research and Exile (Saudi Arabia)*, if Zakah money is given to anyone other than the members of the Prophet's (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) family and they then give it as a gift to any member of the Prophet's (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) family, it is permissible for members of his (Sallallahu'alayhiwasssalam) family to take it and benefit from it.

They cited the following hadith to prove it:-

> The Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) sent me some lamb from the
> Zakah. I sent `Aishah some of it. When the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) came to` Aishah, he asked, "Do you have anything (to
> eat)?" She said, "Nothing, except the lamb that Nusaybah (Umm
> `Atiyyah's nickname) sent us from that which you gave to her. He said,
> "It has reached its proper place. (Muslim and Bukhari)

Here is the another Hadith:-

> It was narrated from Anas that some meat was brought to the Messenger
> of Allah and he said:
>
> "What is this?" It was said: "It was given in charity to Barirah." He
> said: "It is charity for her and a gift for us." (Sunan an-Nasa'i
> 3760)

Secondly, as far as the phrase "Zakat is part of people's impurity" is concerend, it does not mean that "people" who receive Zakat are impure.

In the Hadith scriptures, it has been narrated,

> "The Muslim is not made impure." (Recorded by Nasa'i, Vol. 1, Book 1,
> Hadith 269)
>
> "A believer never becomes impure" (Sahih al-Bukhari 285)

Secondly, as far as the word "people's impurity" is concerned, it does not literally mean that people are impure or the people who receive Zakat are impure rather it is referring to the impurity of wealth in posession of people.

As the hadith scriptures say,

> Allah made Zakat a purifier of the property." (Sahih al-Bukhari 1404)

I hope it answers your question.

Allah Knows Best.

Answer (score 0):

One can interpret this as you do that it's not adequate to the dignity of the family to accept zakat.
On the other hand it can be seen as a preventive measure: the family of the prophet (p.b.u.h) should not enrich through taking zakat. I see in this rather an admonition to those who are in charge that zakat is paid for the community rather than for their own purposes.